# Downloading 7.0.7 - jconn-7.0.7.jar

Tags: jdbc, sybase, jconnect

I am trying to download **jconnect-7.0.7.jar** for Sybase Database from this URL [http://downloads.sybase.com/][1]. But getting error like the site is down. I searched a lot, but cannot find the jar anywhere.

Could anyone let me know where I can get the jar?

Answer (score 1):

Old sybase.com page is not active any more. You can get jConnect 16.0 together with ASE 16.0 directly from sap.com page. The JDBC driver is almost the same as the 7.0.7 version except the version name has changed.